# Something wrong with my canvas loop

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a simple graph that goes back to the beginning after drawing all the way to the canvas width. But for some reason it doesn't goes up iterating after i reset the x value. Where am i doing wrong things?
thnx in advance;

http://fun.qoobx.com/canvas/

just to describe my logic: i watch if the X value gets up to canvas width and then i just reset it.

and here's the script:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var curposY = 0;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var color1 = '02c4f9';

    var i = 0;
    var oldX = 0,
        oldY = parseInt(Math.random()*(40-30)+30),
        newX = 0,
        newY = parseInt(Math.random()*(40-30)+30);

    if (canvas.getContext){

        function drawContent(initialValue){ 

            ctx.strokeStyle = "#"+color1;           
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(oldX,oldY);
            ctx.lineTo(newX,newY);
            ctx.stroke();   

            // console.log('draw');
            console.log(newX);

            // console.log(color1);

            oldX = newX;
            oldY = newY;
            newX = i++;
            newY = parseInt(Math.random()*(45-30)+30);

            if( newX >= 200 ){
                newX = 0;
            } 

            setTimeout(drawContent,10);
        }
        drawContent();

    } else {
        alert('You need Safari or Firefox 1.5+ to see this demo.');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the looping construct in your js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're resetting the `newX` value but not the `i` value, which according to your code has to be reset as well.